# Can you replace Getter's and Setter's methods in java with something else?

Tags: java

is there a way to replace this methods (Getter's and Setter's) with another method or something else that do same work. I am asking that because of my study.

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int sellIn;
    private int quality;

    public Item(String name, int sellIn, int quality) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quality = quality;
        this.sellIn = sellIn;
    }

    public void setSellIn(int sellIn) {
        this.sellIn = sellIn;
    }

    public void setQuality(int quality) {
        this.quality = quality;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getSellIn() {
        return sellIn;
    }

    public int getQuality() {
        return quality;
    }
}
```

Thank a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "something else that do same work"?

Comment: Yes you can, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: You can declare the variables as `public`, but it's not recommended.

Comment: You can call your getters and setters whatever you want; they are just normal methods. Usually you shouldn't but sometimes it makes sense to call them something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to enable a field in a class to be retrieved and updated in Java is through getter and setter methods.

Still, there's [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) that aims to help developers to not write these methods and use annotations instead that will generate getters, setters and other methods like `equals` and `hashCode` for you.

Here's a code sample from the demo in their site:

```
public @Data class Mountain {
    private final String name;
    private final double latitude, longitude;
    private String country;
}
```

It will generate this code:

```
public class Mountain {
    private final String name;
    private final double latitude, longitude;
    private String country;

    public Mountain(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This makes the code compatible with [JavaBeans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf), which is used by several frameworks like Hibernate, JPA, Expression Language, JSF, Spring, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Getters and Setters are convention and nothing else. (Well, to be accurate they are defined in the [JavaBeans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf) but that's not a binding part of the language.) You can name them differently of course if for some reason you don't want to follow the convention; this could cause confusion but it is possible. So for example you could have

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int sellIn;
    private int quality;

    public Item(String name, int sellIn, int quality) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quality = quality;
        this.sellIn = sellIn;
    }

    public void declareSellInAs(int sellIn) {
        this.sellIn = sellIn;
    }

    public void makeQualityBe(int quality) {
        this.quality = quality;
    }

    public String retrieveName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int whatIsSellIn() {
        return sellIn;
    }

    public int howGoodIsTheQuality() {
        return quality;
    }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing anything like that unless you have a **really** good reason though. If you break compatibility to the JavaBeans specification many frameworks which depend on it will have problems with your code.

Comment: Well, the JPA framework uses it so intensively that IMHO it is more than conventions...

Comment: @AndreiI It is used in JPA, yes. And it is also used by other frameworks. Nevertheless, it is not part of the JLS, so it's still just a convention - though a very wide spread one.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, that is valid if you want your item to be a bean. But you don't have to use that. As I said in my answer, you should though.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have added the JavaBean Specification, so as to make it clearer why deviating from it is a bad idea.

Comment: @blalasaadri the "JavaBean Specification" is a very important part :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what do you mean with "not the way to go" ?

Comment: @AndreiI that was because the answer didn't explained the purpose of having getters/setters to follow this specification, the *this* was for the state of the answer (in that moment).